# Making an assignable grid to segue in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I need to implement a grid view of images that requires each segment to segue to another view controller /or View.

My parameters:

I need 260 segments: approx 18px x 18px
Each segment will be numbered (1-260) and have a diffrent (background) image
One segment must be highlighted (a daily square like ical)
You can tap any segment to segue to the next view controller

I have looked at custom TVCells / Buttons but are there more options out there?

Thank you

Comment: I have now also looked at tags for all 260 buttons. The daily highlight I have opted to change the background image using: [(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:dayCount] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for:

- Linking the 1stViewController to the 2ndViewController in the
  storyboard and naming the seque.identifier in the attributes.
- Creating a grid of UIButtons in IB and assigning them individual tags in the attributes (1-260 - don't use 0 as it is a default).

To change the buttons' backgroundImage daily I set up a day-counter integer
   and in the viewDidLoad of the 1stVC coded:

```
   [(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:dayCount] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_Day.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As there were multiple UIButtons, I decided that dragging them all to a IBAction in IB was too long a task so I assinged them programatically using:

```
-(void) assignButtons{
[(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:2] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
} //etc for all 260
```

Then used performSegueWithIdentifier: in a method:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```